# How to specify a minimum JRE minor version in jnlp file?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My application needs to have at least JRE 1.8.0_60. How can I define this?

```
<j2se version="1.8.0_60" .../>
```

means only this Version, right?

Comment: add a `+` as `version="1.8.0_60+"`. and also add a `spec` into the most outer `jnlp` xml tag as `spec="1.8.0_60+"`. for further information check the [documetation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

Comment: thank you, I will try the `+`. But why add the `spec` with the same version? I read the documentation and I thought it concerns the jnlp specification version and not the jre version.